# Salvattore fails processing g expression

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Am getting an error from Salvattore in Chrome and Safari but is not like the one previously mentioned here this is now new.

Am using Chrome 37.

Error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

which points to:

```
g = f.match(/^\s*(\d+)(?:\s?\.(.+))?\s*$/);
```

Now am guessing 'g' is expected to be an array, since there is no validation for g it just blows up, I guess they never expected g to be undefined.

Anybody working on Salvattore that can provide us with an update on when a fix for Chrome and Safari will be put in place?

Can someone also tell me what this expression does? maybe I can work around it